# Change the css of a select link with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, pagination

I am working on an AJAX pagination and I made it by using this code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var pagination = $("#pagination");
  var url = urlProviderOffers;

  updateContent(function(json) {});

  pagination.on('click', "ul a", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var page_to_visit = $(this).text();

    updateContent(function(json) {});

    pagination.find('ul li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');

  });

  function updateContent(callback, page_to_visit) {

    page_to_visit = typeof(page_to_visit) != 'undefined' ? page_to_visit : 1;

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      data: {
        page: page_to_visit
      }
    }).done(function(json) {

      if (json.total > 1) {
        pagination.find("ul li:nth-child(1)").addClass('active');
      }

      callback(json);

    });
  }

  url = template_url.replace(/provider_id_to_change/, providerID);
  return url;
}
});
```

```html
<div id="pagination">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li class="active"><a href="/provider/prov_2/offers?page=1">1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/provider/prov_2/offers?page=2">2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/provider/prov_2/offers?page=3">3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The problem I am having is that, any time I click on one of the links of the pagination, a function is called and inside this function I change the `active` link been visited by the user.

For instance, when my page is loading, the function `updateContent` sets the current page been visited to 1. And after clicking on another link of the pagination, I remove all the added class and add a new `active` class to the selected link.

In my case anytime, when a link is clicked, is set the class of the selected link to `active` and automatically remove the added class and set the active class to the first link.

kindly help me solve this problem

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error from your code because of unbalanced brackets.

Comment: `pagination.find("ul li:nth-child(1)").addClass('active');` adds the active class to the first link.

Comment: Getting syntax error, brackets do not match.